# Making Calculation on Future requests based on priority

Tags: scala

I have a question regarding handling making async operations and taking action based on priority.

Consider the following code:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// mock database call
def isSiteExcludedAtList(listId: Int, siteId: Int): Future[Some[Int]] = Future {
  Some(1)
}

// main logic
def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): Future[String] = {

  val domainFutures: Future[List[Option[Int]]] = Future.traverse(listIds)(listId => isSiteExcludedAtList(listId, domainHash))
  val subDomainFutures: Future[List[Option[Int]]] = Future.traverse(listIds)(listId => isSiteExcludedAtList(listId, subdomainHash))

  // Is there other way?
  for {
    res <- Future.sequence(
      List(
        subDomainFutures.map(res => "subdomain" -> res),
        domainFutures.map(res => "domain" -> res)
      )
    )
  } yield {
    val subdomainExclusion: List[Int] = res.filter(_._1 == "subdomain").flatMap(_._2).flatten
    val domainExclusion: List[Int] = res.filter(_._1 == "domain").flatMap(_._2).flatten
    if (subdomainExclusion.nonEmpty) {
      s"its subdomain exclusion with results: ${subdomainExclusion}"
    }
    else {
      s"its domain exclusion with results: ${domainExclusion}"
    }
  }
}
```

What i want to achieve:

- isSiteExcludedAtList returns Int object from database, this is mocked in my example but its actually and async call to get some int value from some key which contains both listId and siteId from database.
- I want to create subdomainFutures and domainFutures and start to run them *together*
- I want to check if there result from subdomainFutures, if so - its subdomain exclusion and i want to return this
- if all subdomainFutures not return any result - i want to check domainFutures and return result base on this.

*Note*: waiting for only one result of subdomain is optional optimization.

Is there a more pretty way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that because of the way `Futures` work, those will run even if you don't need them. Is that okay for you? If not I would suggest looking into `IO` from **cats-effect**

Comment: I'm actually not must to wait for all futures to complete, if there at least one subdomain result so i can return result of it, otherwise - i need to wait to them all to complete before passing to domain, i would love an example if its possible :) I'm new to `cats-effect`

Comment: I am still confused about something, you want a single result? or all of them? How does that relates with the difference between subdomains and domains? If there is at least one subdomain result you don't want the domain results but you still want all the subdomain ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
    subdomainFutures.map(_.flatten).flatMap { 
       case sds if (sds.nonEmpty) => Future.successful(sds -> Nil)
       case _ => domainFutures.map(_.flatten).map(Nil -> _)
    }.map {
      case (sds, _) if (sds.nonEmpty) => s"subdomain exclusion $sds"
      case (_, ds) if (ds.nonEmpty) => s"domain exclusion $ds"
      case _ => "no exclusion"
    }
```

Or, maybe, pull domain queries up to the same level too:

```
    subdomainFutures.zip(domainFutures)
      .map { case (s,d) = (s.flatten, d.flatten) }
      .map {
        case (sds, _) if (sds.nonEmpty) => s"subdomain exclusion $sds"
        case (_, ds) if (ds.nonEmpty) => s"domain exclusion $ds"
        case _ => "no exclusion"
      }
```

I think, it's more or less the same thing you are doing, just expressed in a little bit more straightforward way IMO.

One downside is it will wait for all subdomain queries to come back even if the very first one returns a result (the second variant looks a little "slicker", but it also waits for all domain queries unconditionally, which is an additional inefficiency).

There are ways to optimize that (nothing is impossible!) but I can't think of any that wouldn't look excessively complicated for the use case to me.

Comment: Consider bucket of 1000 futures for subdomain and 2000 futures for domain, in the first example we are waiting all the 1000 futures of subdomain to finish before starting checking the 2000 futures for domain, which its `O(3000 futures)`, while `Future.sequence` is `O(2000 futures)` since they are starting *together*, the `zip` is also working in the same way from my understanding - wdyth? - btw thank you very much for the response :)

Comment: No, all futures are started at the same time, when you create them. `zip` is pretty much the same thing a `sequence`, just tuples instead of lists. Your `sequence` waits for all futures to complete before it starts doing anything, same as `zip`. The first snippet is a little bit more efficient in that sense: it will not  wait for `domainFutures` to complete, as long as any subdomains are found.

Comment: So lets say i'm doing `Future { 1  }.map { _ => Future { 2 } }`  and `Future { 1 }` takes `t1` time to complete and the second future takes `t2` time to complete, is it no `O(t1 + t2)`? and `Future.sequence(List(Future { 1 }, Future { 2 }))` is `O(max(t1,t2))`?

Comment: or because i defined them as `val` its begin to work on start?

Comment: Oh, got it. thanks @Dima (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ve7iwO36RQ6nQE9G1JPehg)

Comment: Yes, if you do `Future(t1).flatMap(_ => Future(t2))`, that takes t1+t2. But if you do `val fu1 = Future(t1); val fu2 = Future(t2); fu1.flatMap(fu2)`, that's `max(t1,t2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Dima! I missed that part. btw do you think about "pretty" way to do the first suggested without tuppling it? its not so readable to first timer dev which face this code

Comment: I don't know how it can be any more pretty than that! :D If by "pretty" you mean "efficient", I think there may be ways to improve here, but (1) it'll certainly make it look less pretty, (2) will complicate things a lot, and (3) will probably not yield much of a noticeable gain in practice

Comment: Re. "readability", I think, it is actually quite easily readable to anyone with a grasp on a few basic scala  concepts (no cats/zio/scalaz skills required). And as for those, whoo do not, I submit everything would be hard to read ... at first, as long as it is written in native scala, and not just java code with scala syntax. (For the record, can't begin to imaging what's wrong with using tuples ... you are using them too in your question, just in a less obvious way).

Comment: Also i think that `if (sds.nonEmpty)` is redundant on the second map

Comment: Got it and appreciate, thank you @Dima

Comment: It's not redudnant. `sds` will always be set to _something_ ... The way to check if you found a subdomain is to see if it is nonempty.

Comment: oh right, its late for me, thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

So you want to fetch both domains and subdomains in parallel, you also want to concurrently execute as many `isSiteExcludedAtList` as possible. And additionally, if there is at least one subdomain, you want to cancel the domains.

That can easily be represented using **cats-effect** and **fs2** by taking advantage of `IO`
*(The following code assumes that `isSiteExcludedAtList` returns an `IO[Option[Int]]`)*

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.syntax.all._
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.concurrent.SignallingRef

def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): IO[Unit] = {
  def parallelStreamFor(siteId: Int): Stream[IO, Int] =
    Stream
      .emits(listIds)
      .covary[IO]
      .parEvalMapUnordered(maxConcurrent = 2)(listId => isSiteExcludedAtList(listId, siteId))
      .collect {
        case Some(result) => result
      }
  
  SignallingRef[IO].of(false).flatMap { signal =>
    val processSubdomains =
      parallelStreamFor(siteId = subdomainHash)
        .evalTap(_ => signal.set(true))
        .compile
        .toList

    val processDomains =
      parallelStreamFor(siteId = domainHash)
        .interruptWhen(signal)
        .compile
        .toList

    (processSubdomains,processDomains).parTupled
  } flatMap {
    case (subdomainExclusions, domainExclusions) =>
      if (subdomainExclusions.nonEmpty)
        IO.println(s"Its subdomain exclusion with result: ${subdomainExclusions}")
      else if (domainExclusions.nonEmpty)
        IO.println(s"Its domain exclusion with result: ${domainExclusions}")
      else
        IO.println("All subdomains and domains are included!")
  }
}
```

A couple of considerations:

- If the order of elements matters, then replace `parEvalMapUnordered` with just `parEvalMap` which is a little bit less efficient.
- Adjust the value of `maxConcurrent` so it makes sense given your workload.
- If you would rather keep each stream synchronous and just run both concurrently we can replace the `parEvalMapUnordered` + `parEvalMapUnordered` with a single call to `evalMapFilter`
- You can easily integrate this in your codebase without needing to refactor too much thanks to `IO.fromFuture` and `IO.unsafeToFuture()`

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kTcAhMDnR4ulAlJ9ehd7dQ/16)*.

---

## Edit

> **OLD AND WRONG ANSWER**

If I understood the problem correctly, you want to stop processing at the first result to return a `Some`

If you are open to using **cats-effect**, that is pretty easy to achieve like this:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.syntax.all._

def isSiteExcludedAtList(listId: Int, siteId: Int): IO[Option[Int]] =
  IO.println(s"Computing for ${listId} - ${siteId}").as(Some(10))

def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): IO[Unit] = {
  val processSubdomains =
    listIds.collectFirstSomeM(listId => isSiteExcludedAtList(listId, siteId = subdomainHash))

  val processDomains =
    listIds.collectFirstSomeM(listId => isSiteExcludedAtList(listId, siteId = domainHash))

  processSubdomains.flatMap {
    case Some(subdomainExclusion) =>
      IO.println(s"Its subdomain exclusion with result: ${subdomainExclusion}")

    case None =>
      processDomains.flatMap {
        case Some(domainExclusion) =>
          IO.println(s"Its domain exclusion with result: ${domainExclusion}")

        case None =>
          IO.println("All subdomains and domains are included!")
      }
  }
}
```

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kTcAhMDnR4ulAlJ9ehd7dQ/2)*

> **Note**: Another approach would be to tag each computation with is origin *(domain, or subdomain)* and combine all them in a big list and perform a single `collectFirstSomeM` both are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate about `collectFirstSomeM` on futures? what do its really do? its will not wait to other futures to complete?

Comment: @ZviMints note that I am using `IO` not `Future` anyways yeah it runs each `IO` sequentially until it finds the first one to be a `Some` and stops there. I am not totally sure how would it behave with `Future`, I guess it is worth giving a shot. Just remember to move the `val processDomains =` inside the `None` case of the `processSubdomains.flatMap {` branch, otherwise it will run those `Futures`

Comment: Thanks :) - Can you provide maybe with Futures instead also? - to make cooperation

Comment: Also with futures i guess that `.flatMap` is blocking which its not my intention on the main question

Comment: @ZviMints I just did the edit. About `flatMap` being blocking, it depends on your definition of blocking; it is not in the sense that no thread will be blocked. but it does represent sequestration, thus the next `Future` won't run until the first one finishes. - WDYM with it not being your intention?

Comment: I want to run all the threads together, both domain and subdomain. when the subdomain are finished, i will check if there result and will check on domain otherwise. its what i did on `Future.sequence` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: In your example, you first running subdomain and then starts the domain tasks

Comment: @ZviMints I just updated my answer with the latest version of the code, I also deleted a couple of comments that are no longer relevant _(I would suggest you do the same)_. - `IO` is useful because it is just a description of computation, which allows us to define arbitrary execution flow through combinators. As you can see in my example, it is quite simple to get everything running concurrently and also cancel the domains stream; with `Futures` that is not an easy task. If you are interested in more check the _"Programs as Values"_ series from Fabio: https://systemfw.org/archive.html

Comment: Amazing @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez , learned a lot - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to describe how to improve a bit your code while still using futures, but I'm a bit confused of what this code is doing. What is this number that `isSiteExcludedAtList` returns? Is it an identifier and you want to collect identifiers for all list ids, and you're only concerned with that you don't want to query using `domainHash` if it's enough to use `subdomainHash`? That's what your code seems to be doing but then, if I understand correctly the answer above, the one with cats-effect and `collectFirstSomeM`, then that code looks only for the first result that is `Some(number)` and then stops. For example, if the first ever call to `isSiteExcludedAtList` will return `Some(1)` then we won't call anything more.

So, I have three answers for you.

1. This is if you want to collect a list of ints and you only want to avoid calling `isSiteExcludedAtList` with `domainHash` if calls `subdomainHash` give you some results already. In this case you can chain both `Future.traverse` and call the second one only if the first one returns no results.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// mock database call
def isSiteExcludedAtList(listId: Int, siteId: Int): Future[Some[Int]] = 
  Future { Some(1) }

// main logic
def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): Future[String] =
  for {
    res1   <- Future.traverse(listIds)(isSiteExcludedAtList(_, subdomainHash))
    subIds =  res1.flatten
    res2   <- if (subIds.isEmpty) 
                Future.traverse(listIds)(isSiteExcludedAtList(_, domainHash)) 
              else 
                Future.successful(Nil)
    domIds =  res2.flatten
  } yield 
    if (subIds.nonEmpty)
      s"its subdomain exclusion with results: ${subIds}"
    else if (domIds.nonEmpty)
      s"its domain exclusion with results: ${domIds}"
    else
      "no exclusion"
```

2. This is if you look for the first result that indicates that the listId is excluded and then you want to query no more. In that case, all calls to `isSiteExcludedAtList` must be chained, i.e. you call a next one only when you get no result from the previous one. It can be done with recursion:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// mock database call
def isSiteExcludedAtList(listId: Int, siteId: Int): Future[Option[Int]] = 
  Future { Some(1) }

def isSiteExcludedAtList(listIds: List[Int], hash: Int): Future[Option[Int]] = 
  listIds match {
    case Nil => 
      Future.successful(None)
    case head :: tail => 
      isSiteExcludedAtList(head, hash).flatMap {
        case Some(id) => Future.successful(Some(id))
        case None     => isSiteExcludedAtList(tail, hash)
      }
  }

// if you use Scala 3, change this to an enum
sealed trait Exclusion
final case class SubdomainExclusion(id: Int) extends Exclusion
final case class DomainExclusion(id: Int) extends Exclusion
case object NoExclusion extends Exclusion

// main logic
def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): Future[String] =
  isSiteExcludedAtList(listIds, subdomainHash).flatMap {
    case Some(id) => 
      Future.successful(SubdomainExclusion(id))
    case None     => 
      isSiteExcludedAtList(listIds, domainHash).map {
        case Some(id) => DomainExclusion(id)
        case None     => NoExclusion
      }
  }.map {
    case SubdomainExclusion(id) => s"subdomain exclusion $id"
    case DomainExclusion(id)    => s"domain exclusion: $id"
    case NoExclusion            => "no exclusion"
  }
```

3. And the third possibility is that instead of using `Future.traverse` and asking for each `listId` separately, you will implement a query that will return all excluded ids for a given hash - `subdomainHash` or `domainHash`, and then you will just check if a common set of your `listIds` and ids returned by that query is non-empty. The code will be similar to that from my first answer, but it will make only two calls to the database. I'm writing about it because from my experience it's a common pattern in dealing with databases: we have some already written queries and as our code becomes more complex we start to use those queries in loops, which leads to sub-optimal performance, while instead we could write a bit more complex query which we would call only once.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// mock database call
def isSiteExcludedAtListBulk(siteId: Int): Future[Set[Int]] = 
  Future { Set(10, 20, 30) }

// main logic
def isExcluded(listIds: List[Int], subdomainHash: Int, domainHash: Int): Future[String] =
  for {
    excludedSubIds <- isSiteExcludedAtListBulk(subdomainHash)
    subIds         =  listIds.filter(excludedSubIds)
    excludedDomIds <- if (subIds.isEmpty) 
                        isSiteExcludedAtListBulk(domainHash)
                      else 
                        Future.successful(Set.empty)
    domIds         =  listIds.filter(excludedDomIds)
  } yield 
    if (subIds.nonEmpty)
      s"its subdomain exclusion with results: ${subIds}"
    else if (domIds.nonEmpty)
      s"its domain exclusion with results: ${domIds}"
    else
      "no exclusion"
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! - the problem that i can see in this answer its that you making sequence of async operations one by the other - and this i want to avoid, since, for example in your second example/first example you chaining in isSiteExcludedAtList and this is very slow, also on first example for  `Future.traverse(listIds)(isSiteExcludedAtList(_, domainHash)) ` which starts after `Future.traverse(listIds)(isSiteExcludedAtList(_, subdomainHash)) `ends

Comment: If even one call to the database is costly, then the more reason to try to limit their number. Even if you call the query asynchronously, but many times, the cost will still be there - some of the calls will be unnecessary, and they may slow down your access to the database.

Personally, I would go with the third option. It's the least number of calls, and quite probably the fastest.

Comment: I have SLA's. I must to run them in parallel and I'm not caring about how much load its making on the database.

Comment: I must run all the futures to get a valid response, hense, for performance, I'm running them in parallel. and this what i asked in the question :)

Comment: Okay, that's different from what I thought :)
Take a look at this then: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cjwTYkHxQTyE5XXZIC55xg
It's a bit hacky, and it will work only if there is for sure a result - otherwise the future will never finish. It launches all the calls at once and then the first call that return with Some(number) makes the future finish with success.

Comment: Thanks :) cool use of Promise, its actually still bit different - since i need to check first if `all` futures of subdomain are finished first before checking domain

Comment: Also pay attention the the for comprehension is actually evaluated one by one, hence it's running not in parallel.

Comment: The futures are created one by one, but each of them run in parallel.

Comment: Oh right, because the `p.future` is when they are really begin to run right?

Comment: No. Every call to `isSiteExcludedAtList` creates a new future and that future starts to run at the moment of creation. But the for/yield loop does not wait for it to finish. It very quickly goes through all the combinations of listIds and hashes, calls `isSiteExcludedAtList`, creates all the futures, and ends. Then you get `p.future` and wait for any of those futures to finish with a valid result.